# How to properly combine RxJava / Vert.x Data Fetchers / GraphQL Subscriptions

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, vert.x

I have the following test code:

```
  FlowableOnSubscribe<SomeObj> fos;

  private void init() {
    fos = emitter -> {
      try {
        while(true) {
          SomeObj someObj = readFromDataInputStream();
          emitter.onNext(someObj);
          System.out.println("Emitted object");
        }
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
        emitter.onError(e);
      }
    };
  }

  public Single<String> doWork() {
    Flowable<String> myFlow = Flowable.defer(() -> 
      Flowable.create(fos, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
        .cache()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io(), false)
        .doOnSubscribe(x -> doSomethingToTriggerDataInputStream())
        .map(x -> convertMyCustomObjectToString(x))
      );
    );

    // lastOrError/singleOrError end up blocking :(
    return myFlow.firstOrError(); 
  }

  public VertxDataFetcher<CompletionStage<String>> vertxDataFetcherTest() {
    return new VertxDataFetcher<>((env, future) -> {
      try {
        future.complete(doWork().to(SingleInterop.get()));
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
        future.fail();
      }
    });
  }

  public DataFetcher<CompletionStage<String>> dataFetcherTest() {
    return env -> doWork().to(SingleInterop.get());
  }
```

If I run the example code it hangs after the first successful use.  In other words, it will run once on initial webpage load but if I do a refresh in my browser (Ctrl F5), it hangs and no longer completes the call.

FWIW, with a little bit of debugging it looks like the 
defer/map calls are happening on RxCachedThreadScheduler1, and after a webpage refresh it hangs in the defer call with RxCachedThreadScheduler2.

If I switch to using a separate input stream for each call it does not get hung up. The example I followed is here([RxJava: Feed one stream (Observable) as the input of another stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321272/)…).

However, that does not work with my design as it needs 1 shared connection that remains open the entire time. This is because I want the GraphQL subscription to be able to capture anything emitted on the data input stream.  If I have multiple/separate socket connections, the GraphQL subscription input stream will miss anything emitted on the non-subscription input streams. (Unless the best option is to have every other input stream also emit to the GraphQL subscription stream, which I'm not sure how to do...)

As a sidenote, does it matter if I use VertxDataFetcher vs DataFetcher in this scenario? I am currently using the DataFetcher to run my example. If I need to switch to the VertxDataFetcher I'm not sure how to properly cast the types to get that method to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of concerning stuff going on.

Your emitter is clearly blocking, so the most important change you can try is call `.observeOn(RxHelper.blockingScheduler(vertx))` when creating your `Flowable`. Read more [here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java2/) about how to use the proper schedulers.

That will probably not fix your issue though. You're probably reading data in a blocking, conventional Java IO way with `readFromDataInputStream()`, which might be thread safe but it's almost certainly does not support concurrent readers. You are trying to use concurrent readers, implicitly, as long as `readFromDataInputStream()` eventually reads from the same IO. See [Java: Concurrent reads on an InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159183/java-concurrent-reads-on-an-inputstream)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for. The example is for one instance of the emitter, with multiple observers on it. I have also tried the RxHelper since this original post but it didn't work (as you also mentioned)